# Flex-Container not scrollable although overflow set

Tags: css

Now what I was trying is making a scrollable flex container, and all it's children EXCEPT THE FILTER BAR(see image below) have height 100% cuz I read that they require a 100% height.
Those 3 screenshots posted on imgur show the 3 important containers:
`https://imgur.com/a/m1t2vQo`. And this codepen link contains the html content for those 3 containers including their css properties: `https://codepen.io/Proudyy/pen/bGYvegp`
Although I also set the overflow auto property to the container containing the little squared images, it does not let itself scroll.

Answer (score 0):

change the container overflow to scroll because auto add scrollbars only when necessary

Comment: When changing the container overflow to scroll, the scrollbar appears, but it's not scrollable at all.

Comment: it's because the container has not exceeded the viewport

Comment: So how can I fix that?